# parsley.js regex not working

Tags: regex, parsley.js

I've created a regex using RegExr and it works there. The pattern is:

```
data-parsley-pattern="/[1|2|3|4|5|i|l|I|L][a-k|m-n|p-z|A-K|M-N|P-Z][a-k|m-n|p-z|A-K|M-N|P-Z][a-k|m-n|p-z|A-K|M-N|P-Z][a-k|m-n|p-z|A-K|M-N|P-Z][a-k|m-n|p-z|A-K|M-N|P-Z]"
```

I'm trying to limit submissions to numbers 1-5 (but also accepting "i" and "l") and then five letters (excluding "l" and "o"). Everything is case-insensitive.

The expression works correctly, just not as a parsley pattern.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Might be able to simplify that a bit: `[1-5ilIL][a-km-np-zA-KM-NP-Z]{5}`

Comment: Other than there is a missing delimiter on the regex (should cause error), its the same as `[1-5ILil|][A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z|]{5}`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't writing the regex correctly.

You'd need to change the pattern to:

```
data-parsley-pattern="[1-5ilIL][a-km-np-zA-KM-NP-Z][a-km-np-zA-KM-NP-Z][a-km-np-zA-KM-NP-Z][a-km-np-zA-KM-NP-Z][a-km-np-zA-KM-NP-Z]"
```

and also you can shortcut it using `{}`

```
data-parsley-pattern="[1-5ilIL][a-km-np-zA-KM-NP-Z]{5}"
```

If you want to allow from 1 up to 5 times your class you can use:

```
data-parsley-pattern="[1-5ilIL][a-km-np-zA-KM-NP-Z]{1,5}"
```

Btw, if you want to ensure that `/` is present, then you need to add it and the beginning of the regex. I've just removed since I though it was a typo.

The **pipe |** is used to separate patterns for instance `wordA|wordB` what will match wordA or wordB. But you were separating the characters inside a class `[]`. The **class** allows you chose what are the characters allowed, for instance [aBpu] this will match only one character a, B, p or u.